# undefined method `update_attributes' for #<Array:0xb5d61608> rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the below action in my controller

```
cust = Customer.where(email: 'test@testing.com').pluck(:post_id)
@posts = Post.find(cust)
if params[:status]
  if @posts.update_attribute(:customer_id, customer_id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: 'test'}
    end
  end
end
```

The above update_attribute is throwing undefined method error.

cust will return array of ids such as `[1,2,3]`

How can I do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
@posts = Post.where(id: cust)
@posts.update_all(customer_id: customer_id)
```

It constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database.

Answer (score 0):

try to alter the queries in the following way

cust = Customer.where(email: 'test@testing.com').first.pluck(:post_id)

This will return a single customer, then do the same thing with post @posts = Post.where(id: cust).first

However, if you want multiple records in @posts, then you'll need to loop through them all and update individually.

@posts.each do |post|
  if post.update_attribute(:customer_id, customer_id)
  end
end

Comment: Why do I need to add first? I used pluck to generate array of values not for first id alone

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> cust = Customer.where(email: 'test@testing.com').pluck(:post_id)
>
> Post.update_all({:customer_id, customer_id}, {id: cust})

we can include the where clause in the update_all query itself